# TCP send buffer doesn't get filled and no more data gets added, what happens?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

TCP send buffer doesn't get filled and no more data gets added, what happens? Does the items in the buffer just don't get sent or is there a coutdown/timeout where if a buffer does get items added to it but doesn't get filled in X amount of time, it gets sent?

Answer (score 0):

The data will be sent after a (short) while even if the buffer is never filled to capacity. This can be disabled by setting the `TCP_NODELAY` option ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)).